# Django Timezones with offsite server

Tags: django

I have a django project running on a digital ocean server in Toronto Canada. I have clients in Winnipeg and Toronto both using the application. I am confused on the correct method of storing and retrieving dates using Django.

In my settings.py I have:

```
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Toronto'
USE_I18N = True
USE_L10N = True
USE_TZ = True
```

And in my various python code when I am storing dates in the project I use:

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.utils.timezone import utc

myTimeStamp = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
```

Then to show the time in my Django Templates I use:

```
{% load tz %}
{{myTimeStamp|localtime}}
```

When I view this template in Winnipeg, the time is wrong by 1 hour (it is showing Toronto time)
The easy fix is to change the settings.py to `TIME_ZONE = 'America/Winnipeg` but then I would assume people in Toronto would be seeing the wrong time (Winnipeg time).

The challenge I'm having is that people are writing to the database from multiple timezones and reviewing data from multiple timezones, and I'm confused as heck as you can tell! Any help is appreciated

Where am I going wrong here?
My assumption is that you write to the database in the timezone where the actual project is running, then view the time in localtime using the template tags to display appropriately?

Comment: All of these issues are directly addressed in [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/), so if you haven't read that you definitely should. Briefly: 1) all datetimes are stored in UTC, so there's no need to convert anything when writing to the database; 2) `localtime()` does the same thing as `USE_TZ`, so there's no need for that; 3) use `activate()` to ensure that datetimes are converted to the desired timezone on display; 4) there's no way for Django to know the timezone of the user, you have to determine that yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I have been reading documentation and it is quite hard to follow for me. It looks like I need to enable the `django.template.context_processors.tz` and then set a timezone for each user group so that the templates render using their specific timezone. I'm just not sure how to set this context variable.

Comment: No, you just need to [`activate()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone) the time zone you want. Once you do that the display will automatically be correct. ("When you enable time zone support, Django converts aware datetime objects to the current time zone when they’re rendered in templates.") The hard part is knowing what the right time zone is, as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/timezones/#selecting-the-current-time-zone).

Comment: Ok thanks again, I think I got it. Do you see any issue with adding a field to the user model `t_zone = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "America/Winnipeg") ` then in the view I can put `timezone.activate(pytz.timezone(self.request.user.t_zone))` into  `def get_context_data` ? 
I will know ahead of time where the users main timezone will be, so I can add it as users are added.

Comment: That should work fine.